# Expo build fails on "Run fastlane" with unknown error for iOS in production

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to build my expo app for Test Flight. Pre-build works fine and building for development works fine as well. When I try to do

```
npx eas build --profile production --platform ios
```

The build fails with an unknown error.

Running Expo 46+

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development-simulator": {
      "extends": "development",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I would expect this build to succeed just like the development builds

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured this out. Turns out the error was

error: exportArchive: exportOptionsPlist error for key "iCloudContainerEnvironment": value "Development" is not allowed

I need to change

```
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-document-picker",
        {
          "iCloudContainerEnvironment": "Development"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

from development to production.